# Yes/No :Is $ R(V) \subset (ker(V^T))^⊥.$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following statement is true/false ?

> Let $V : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation. If $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$
>   ,define  $W^{⊥} = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n| (x, y) = 0  \ \text{for all x} \in W \}$
>   then   $ R(V) \subset (ker(V^T))^⊥.$

My attempt : I thinks this statement is false from rank - nullity theorem

$\dim W^{\perp} = \dim R(V)  - \dim W$

so $ R(V) = (ker(V^T))^⊥.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=Vx$ and $u\in Ker(V^T)$, then $u^TV=0$ and thus also $u^Ty=0$. So $Im(V)\subset Ker(V^T)^\perp$.

On the other hand, if $u^Ty=0$ for all $u\in Ker(V^T)$, that is, $u^TV=0\implies u^Ty=0$, also implies $rank(V)=rank(V|y)$, so that $y\in Im(V)$.

So yes, there is equality, but that makes the statement not wrong, as the subset relation usually includes the equality of sets by convention. So $\subset$ means the same as $\subseteq$, the strict subset property is written as $\subsetneq$, $\subsetneqq$ or similar.